# Add Collection Description to Shopify Product Page

Tags: collections, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I have setup collections for all the vendors on our store.

I want to show the vendor collection description under the tab Brand on the product page.

I am using the tabs studio app on shopify, so the tab is showing but it is blank.

```
<div class="Brand">
<p>{% for collections in product.collections %}
{% if collection.title == product.vendor %}
{{ collection.description }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</p>
</div>
```

So for example products with vendor Sarah Jessica Parker, would show the following description under the brand tab

Inspired by her obsession with style and fashion and her love of layering unexpected fragrances, Sarah Jessica Parker has gone from strength to strength as she moves from being one of the most famous and successful women in television to being a fashion entrepreneur. Her fragrance ‘Lovely’ was released in 2005 to great success, encouraging her to continue with producing women’s fragrances. She next released her second fragrance ‘Covet’ in 2007 and in 2009 launched a series of fragrances from the ‘Lovely’ collection; ‘Dawn’, ‘Endless’ and ‘Twilight’.

Available at The Beauty Store are each of Sarah Jessica Parker’s best selling fragrances including ‘Lovely’, ‘Covet’, the ‘Lovely’ collection of ‘Dawn’, ‘Endless’ and ‘Twilight’ and also her ‘SJP NYC’ fragrance. Choose from Eau de Parfum or Eau de Toilette and a selection of volumes to get the right fragrance strength for you that can either take pride of place on your dresser or slip easily into your handbag for a night out. Choose a Sarah Jessica Parker fragrance for perfume that is quintessentially beautiful.

Product page example - https://www.thebeautystore.com/collections/sarah-jessica-parker/products/sarah-jessica-parker-lovely-edp-spray-100ml-rollerball-10ml-gold-clutch-bag

Answer (score 0):

Since a product can be assigned to multiple collections in shopify, you may want to manually designate the exact collection that you want to output description with. To do this, you can create a collection metafield that contains the description you want to output, and then display it with something like    `{% for collection in collection.metafields.custom.brands.value %} {{ collection.description }} {% endfor %}` . Here's a page about metafiled: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/metafield

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. What I am trying to achieve is to show the vendor (collection) description automatically on the product page for SEO purposes.